# Mura CMS "Cannot connect to localhost" after install?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo, mura

I just installed the basic Mura CMS package and when trying to run for the first time, instead of launching the wizard to finish installation it says "cannot connect to localhost/index.cfm"

Any tips? What am I missing?

Comment: I would assume you don't have your web server running but you need to give more details about your configuration. Also you tags it with Railo, but Railo has been dead for several years you should upgrade to Lucee, there have been several important security patches.

Comment: +100 on the upgrading to Lucee tip. You really need to do that. On your issue, it could be a port conflict (which is still a configuration issue). Give some more details.

Comment: How about http://localhost:8888/index.cfm?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll give Lucee a shot.  My server *was* running though...that's the weird part. (I'd see the basic pages showing Tomcat and Apache were running...)

Comment: @m_evangelista - nope, still fails .I'm trying to uninstall the previous instance of Lucee and start fresh, and now my Tomcat server won't recognize login credentials...even though I've modified the users.xml file.

Comment: @Miguel-F - roger that. I'm working on upgrading to Lucee.